# error: ‘SHGetKnownFolderPath’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux, mingw, mingw32

I know this question asked before, my CPP file is :

```
#include <shlobj.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PWSTR pszPath;
    HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_Startup,0,NULL,&pszPath);
}
```

And i am using Linux Mingw compiler to compile it for windows by this command :

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc hub.cpp
```

or

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ hub.cpp
```

And i get :

```
In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
error: ‘SHGetKnownFolderPath’ was not declared in this scope
                 &pszPath);
                     ^
```

Adding these to the header doesn't help, and i get same error:

```
#define WINVER 0x0600
#include <windows.h>
```

or

```
#define WINVER 0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
```

And I've looked into **shlobj.h**, and **SHGetKnownFolderPath** is in it.

How can i fix it ?

**EDIT** :

The change my friend **ssbssa** suggested in the comments to put `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600 before #include <shlobj.h>` , raise a new error and a new note :

```
hub.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
hub.cpp:8:69: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const KNOWNFOLDERID& {aka const _GUID&}’ from expression of type ‘const GUID* {aka const _GUID*}’
  HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_Startup,0,NULL,&pszPath);
                                                                     ^
In file included from hub.cpp:2:0:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/shlobj.h:755:10: note: in passing argument 1 of ‘HRESULT SHGetKnownFolderPath(const KNOWNFOLDERID&, DWORD, HANDLE, WCHAR**)’
   STDAPI SHGetKnownFolderPath (REFKNOWNFOLDERID rfid, DWORD dwFlags, HANDLE hToken, PWST
```

I can see the error say , It expect a pointer and I gave him an adress, but i don't know how to declare it in the right way.

Comment: Adding `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600` before `#include <shlobj.h>` works for me, so where did you put it?

Comment: @ssbssa thank you for answering , I've update the question with new errors!

Comment: If you use gcc, the code should compile without any changes.
But if you use g++, you need to remove the `&` before `FOLDERID_Startup`, because for c++ it's a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: @ssbssa , thank you, make an answer , add **initguid.h** and **knownfolders.h** to header and remove **&** and use **i686-w64-mingw32-gcc** for compiler, so i can accept it ,sir.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x06000000` before `#include <windows.h>`